# OpenGL drawing earth how to scale points

Tags: opengl, math

I have problem because i want to draw points on sphere but i dont knew how to scale them correct.

```
R = 6400km <- R of earth
r = 6400m <- r of earth in my program
w = r/R;
```

Each point have hight h.
x = lattitude, y =longtitude

My problem is with height. Could you tell me what i have wrong.

```
 x = (r+h*w) * cos(x *  PI / 180.0) * cos(y * PI / 180.0)
 y = (r+h*w)* cos(x *  PI / 180.0) * sin(y * PI / 180.0)
 z = (r+h*w) *sin(x * PI / 180.0)
```

This is what is when i set w = 0.01. When i set w = r/R i see only artefacts
[image: img]

Comment: What is "wrong"? If it's that your mountains may be invisible, it's because even Mt. Everest, at its 8800m, is only just 0.1% higher than your average Earth circumsphere. Try exaggerating your heights a bit.

Comment: I don't think that is wrong ... Earth from space is not bumpy but if you flyby closer then you see the mountains. I think that is more the matter of lighting then model coordinates exaggeration. Add normals and directional diffuse light

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
x=scale*(re+h)*cos(a)*cos(b);
y=scale*(re+h)*cos(a)*sin(b);
z=scale*(rp+h)*sin(a);
```

- re - equator radius
- rp - polar radius
- h - height
- a <-0.5*PI,+0.5*PI>
- b <       0, 2.0*PI>

your scaling of height seems OK maybe the problem is

- absence of brackets (some compilers make a mess without proper bracketing)
- wrong PI ... usually math defines: M_PI
- cos,sin handle usually radians but i have seen also degrees in some libs make sure what is right for you
- wrong angle intervals

What exactly is wrong? Image or more detail info will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have the vector appears to be in the right direction.  I'm not sure why you are multiplying by w, don't you just want

```
x = (r+h) * cos(latitude * PI / 180.0) * cos(longitude * PI / 180.0)
y = (r+h) * cos(latitude * PI / 180.0) * sin(longitude * PI / 180.0)
z = (r+h) * sin(latitude * PI / 180.0)
```